# need help on searching complex string using sed or awk or grep

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have huge text file which contains tons of multi line records of some page views and purchases made by various users. each record is separated by five dashes say '-----' and end with string 'done'. Each record contains userid string such as 'xyz', purchase string as 'purchased'. same userid may contain different records as well

I'm trying to find all records from a specific user say 'xyz' who have purchased the item.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a sample of the file, possibly replacing confidential data with `xyz` as you have.

Comment: and what have to tried so far? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n-----"} /xyz/ && /purchased/' file
```

If that doesn't do what you want, post some SMALL sample input and the expected output from that input.